# Using perl to delete differente file that name end by diefferent name extension Like dynamic date and hour

Tags: perl, glob

I want to delete many file in my directory  the problem is that the extension of that  is not the same. the end is dynamic like:
.dat_20220526_061224

.dat_20220525_041226

.dat_20220514_081212

this extension is dynamic is change but there have same model

please somebody could help me
thanks!

this is my code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = "D:/perl-projet/";

if ( -e $dir)
{
    
    unlink $dir . "log.dat_20220518_233007"; #this ligne is work quand i put all name of the file ( the was been deleted)
    
    #unlink(glob("${$dir}log.dat_???));      #this ligne didn"t work
    
    
    #unlink glob "$dir/*.dat_";           # this ligne didn"t too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
glob("*.dat_*");
```

or

```perl
glob("*.dat_????????_??????");
```

or

```perl
grep /\.dat_\d{8}_\d{6}\z/, glob("*");;
```

Comment: Thank you  the code work  it delete all file that i wanted  i use the first proposition: glob("*.dat_*");  more thank you